# Org mode attachments: how to change the default directory for added attachment folders?

Tags: org-mode

I am using org mode and its attachment functionality, letting me make a directory attached to a task (<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>). The default folder is not the one I would like it to be. How can I change the default folder? Can I somehow call the function `org-attach-set-directory` in my init file to change this default folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came here looking for how to have different `org-attach-directory` values based on different file names or folder locations of the org file. Ended up using advice around `org-attach` and a let to change `org-attach-id-dir` based on a regexp of the file I've dispatched org-attach from.

```
(defun alec-org-attach (orig-func &rest args)
  (if (string-match "work-project-notes" (buffer-file-name))
      (let ((org-attach-id-dir "C:\\Users\\alec\\my\\alt\\dir\\org-attach\\"))
        (funcall orig-func))
      (funcall orig-func)))

(advice-add 'org-attach :around #'alec-org-attach)
```

I know it answers my question, which is more advanced than OP's question, but I didn't see it elsewhere so I felt compelled to post. Happy emacs-ing folks!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 (setq org-attach-directory "/path/to/org-attach/directory/") ;; Note trailing /
```

Comment: Note that for recent Org mode (>= 9.3), this variable is obsolete. It will still work since it is aliased to the variable `org-attach-id-dir` which replaced it, but eventually the alias is going to go away.

Comment: Indeed - that's what `C-h v' gives for the "org-attach-directory" variable.